# Adding float64 values, the fractional value disappears for the result

Tags: go

```
package main


import (
  "fmt"
  "os"
  "bufio"
  "strconv"
)

func main() {

    var _ = strconv.Itoa 
  
    var d float64 = 4.0

    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)

    var b float64
   
    scanner.Scan()

    b, _ = strconv.ParseFloat(scanner.Text(), 64)
  
    fmt.Println(float64(d + b))
    
}
```

Comment: please ignore the float64() at the last line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you print the value it's using the default representation. From the [`fmt` documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/):

```
The default format for %v is:
  ...
  float32, complex64, etc: %g
  ...

The default precision for ... %g it is the smallest number of digits necessary
to identify the value uniquely.
```

Here's your code modified to demonstrate this:

```golang
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "os"
  "bufio"
  "strconv"
)

func main() {
    var d float64 = 4.0
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
    for {
        fmt.Printf("Enter a number: ")
        scanner.Scan()
        b, err := strconv.ParseFloat(scanner.Text(), 64)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            continue
        }
        result := b + d
        fmt.Println("\nResult:")
        fmt.Printf("\t%%v: %v\n", result)
        fmt.Printf("\t%%g: %g\n", result)
        fmt.Printf("\t%%f: %f\n\n", result)
    }
}
```

```sh
$ go run test.go
Enter a number: 5

Result:
        %v: 9
        %g: 9
        %f: 9.000000

Enter a number: 5.5

Result:
        %v: 9.5
        %g: 9.5
        %f: 9.500000

Enter a number: 7.8910

Result:
        %v: 11.891
        %g: 11.891
        %f: 11.891000

Enter a number:
```

Comment: Thanks, with this in mind i just specified my format with - fmt.Printf("%.1f \n",d + b)